# Code number auto-generated when publishing asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, web

I have an ASP.NET website project built in .NET 4.0
And that source code has been provided by Customer.
When I publish website by using Build menu and choose Publish selection.
Then always all aspx files auto-generated with header like this:

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" 
    inherits="AspxPages_FrmAdminTeam, App_Web_2l11jqjv" theme="LMAT" %>
```

And the DLL files like this: `App_Web_2l11jqjv.dll`

Sorry, but this is strange with me, what is this code? `2l11jqjv`

And How can I disable this code auto-generated setting when publishing website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET compilation tool uses random names for the assemblies that are generated during compilation. The name of the assembly changes every time that the application is recompiled.

Thus `2l11jqjv` is a random name choosen by the compliler.

References: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> This Code is Random number.  For Changing name of dll, Under the
>   project properties in Visual Studio, change the "Assembly Name"
>   property to be whatever you want the dll to be named. 
>   let me know if u
>   help this.